# How to make React final form 'Field' value change on date picker event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I want to create a date range field, such that on clicking a input field I would open up a date picker component and on selecting a date range. I would want to populate the input field with selected range.

What I done so far:

I created a input field which is wrapped by a **Field** component. To the value of the input I have set it to this.state.DateRange. Which I would change based on the date range selected from the DatePicker component.

```
   handleSelect({selection}){
    let startDate = format(selection.startDate, 'DD/M/YYYY');
    let endDate = format(selection.endDate, 'DD/M/YYYY');

    this.setState({
      selection,
      DateRange: `${startDate} - ${endDate}`
    })
    }

    //TextFieldInput is a styled component - styled.input

    render(){

      return (
      <div>
        <Field name='test'>

          {({ input, meta, ...rest }) => (
            <TextFieldInput
              {...input}
              {...meta}
              value={this.state.DateRange}
            />
          )}
        </Field>
            <DateRangePicker
                ranges={[this.state.selection]}
                onChange={this.handleSelect}
          months={2}
          minDate={new Date()}
          showMonthAndYearPickers={false}
          showDateDisplay={false}
          staticRanges={[]}
          inputRanges={[]}
          direction='horizontal'
            />
      </div>
        )
    }
```

What I would want to do:

I am able to set the value of the input field through this method, but I am not able get that value when I press submit. It seems that despite value is been set to the input it isn't passed to form onSubmit(values)

Answer (score 0):

What I can gather, is that you want to set the state of your Parent component from a Child component. However, within `<TextFieldInput/>`, you aren't pointing towards your Parent component state.

Edit: I realise I have not provided a complete answer, let me refactor the code:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind( this );
    this.state = {
      // your state
    };
  }
...

handleSubmit = ( event ) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      DateRange: event.target.name.value
    });

    event.target.reset(); // resets fields
  }
...

<TextFieldInput handleSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } ... />
...
```

Then in the Child component:

```
...
<form onSubmit=( ( e ) => { props.handleSubmit( e ); } }>

  <input value={ props.value } name="DateRange" /> // the handleSubmit sees the value by the input name, allowing multiple inputs if necessary in the future
...
```